# Accumulo Write: Trying to create and insert data from mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, accumulo

I'm trying to write data into tables of Accumulo, using MapReduce.
The following is my mapreduce code for accumulo.

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
AccumuloOutputFormat.setZooKeeperInstance(job, accumuloInstance, zooKeepers);
AccumuloOutputFormat.setDefaultTableName(job, accumuloTableName);
AccumuloOutputFormat.setConnectorInfo(job, accumuloUser, new PasswordToken(accumuloPassword));
```

On executing, i'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TException
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.lib.util.ConfiguratorBase.setConnectorInfo(ConfiguratorBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat.setConnectorInfo(AccumuloOutputFormat.java:94)
    at core.accumulo.mapreduce.AccumuloMapReduceWrite.main(AccumuloMapReduceWrite.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

How would i resolve this ? I have tried and refereed few URL's too. But it couldn't help enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your job classpath is missing the Thrift classes. I assume you are running your job using the standard `hadoop job` commands.

In this case, you have two options:

1. Manually add the necessary jars to your classpath. This is going to be `thrift.jar`, `accumulo-start.jar`, `accumulo-core.jar`, and possibly `accumulo-trace.jar` depending on your version. You'll want to specify these with the `-libjars` option, a more full read-up is available as a [blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/).
2. Use build in Apache Accumulo tools to launch your job. Most versions of Accumulo come with a launcher script called `tool.sh` that will automatically add the appropriate jars for you. It is usually found under `$ACCUMULO_HOME/bin/tool.sh`. Some distributions may call it something else, such as `accumulo-tool`, to disambiguate it from other tools. Examples can be seen in the [user manual](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/examples/mapred.html) (third code block).